# displaying images in mvc.net c#

Tags: c#, image, model-view-controller

i want to display images in mvc.net? help anybody :)... im uploading images through silverlight control and storing them on directory at my hard disk

Comment: what is your platform? ASP.NET? WPF? Silverlight? Winforms?

Answer (score 4):

i assume that you like to create an action which give the picture to the client, that's easy.

```
 public ActionResult ResizedPicture(int pictureId)
 {
   var picturePath= GetPicturePathFor(pictureId);
   return File(picturePath, "image/jpeg"); 
 }
```

The Story is the return a FileResult, they are plenty overload for FileResults, so that can return an Stream, Byte-Array or give the path to a file.

GetPicturePathFor() is a not part of mvc.

Comment: tnx Albert i found the answer at:
http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/689_Uploading_and_Displaying_Files_Using_ASP_NET_MVC_Framework.aspx
if anybody else wants to consult ...